# Identify Version of the Remote Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

How can the version of remote Hadoop cluster be identified through api/web-services? i.e. whether the cluster is 1.x type or 2.x type? Is there any API/web-service available for the same?

I have researched webhdfs? hadoop Filesystem but could not identify the way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask read before asking

Comment: Can you answer the above question? I have spend some good days to research that, but could not find the answer to it?

Comment: I think its rather easy to do -1 to a question than to answer it.

Comment: I'm only to say that. From my search, this is about server and network. You may get better help on server fault. Not much of us here use it. Besides, I'm not the one who vote down. Sorry If I made you think I'm offensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is via identifying the exceptions (more or less a hit & trial method):

If using 1.x API's in client & connecting to 2.x Hadoop Cluster or vicecersa, by:

```
    final String uri = "hdfs://remoteHostName:9000/user/myusername";
    final FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get (URI.create (uri), conf);
```

Then we get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
```

The above exception identifies that the client API & Remote Hadoop Cluster are not compatible but unable to get a absolute method to identify the version of remote Hadoop Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Ambari](http://ambari.apache.org/) installed (as many clusters will, especially those based on HDP) you can get cluster version information by doing a GET to`'http://your.ambari.server/api/v1/clusters'`.  The resulting JSON will contain something that looks like:

```
{ "href" : "http://your.ambari.server/api/v1/clusters",
   "items" : [
      {  "href" : "http://your.ambari.server/api/v1/clusters/c1",
         "Clusters" : { "cluster_name" : "c1",
                        "version" : "HDP-1.2.0"  }  }
   ]
}
```

The full API reference can be found at:
https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/index.md

and the specifics of this call are at:
https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/clusters.md

Cloudera seems to have something that is at least similar, although I don't know if it's backed by Ambari:
http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v1/path__clusters.html

Comment: Thanks Rick for the reply, but the case I am working on, there is no ambari installed & its pure apache installations & need to figure out the versions. Though thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you heck through linux command of ssh. Do you have username and password of that cluster.
Then do bellow command after you will get version of hadoop.

ssh username@cluseterip hadoop version

Then it will ask password of remote machine give password it will give version.

example:: Hadoop 1.1.2

Comment: Yes, that's an option which I have tried earlier & worked too but in this case I don't have the username/password of the server.